# Warning: assignment to free variable ‘skeleton-pair’

Tags: variables, warning, lexical-scoping, dynamic-scoping

Am using the following function, but getting the error

```
In bracemk-balance:
fencones.el:109:9:Warning: assignment to free variable
    ‘skeleton-pair’
```

What is wrong with this?

```
(defun bracemk-balance ()
  "Completing brace marks group."

  (setq skeleton-pair t)

  (global-set-key (kbd "(")  'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
  (global-set-key (kbd "[")  'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
  (global-set-key (kbd "{")  'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
  (global-set-key (kbd "<")  'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)

  (global-set-key (kbd "`")  'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
  (global-set-key (kbd "'")  'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe)
  (global-set-key (kbd "\"") 'skeleton-pair-insert-maybe))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just a warning.

With your `setq` you're assigning a value to a *global variable*. Emacs is just letting you know this.

You didn't *explicitly tell* Emacs that `skeleton-pair` is a global variable. To do that, use `(defvar skeleton-pair)` (no initial value). Then you won't see the warning.  That's the way to tell Emacs that a variable is "special" - scoped dynamically.

If you don't tell Emacs that, then Emacs tells you when you use such a variable -- in particular in case you weren't aware of it.  (If you're aware of it then you should tell Emacs: `(defvar skeleton-pair)`.)

Emacs is letting you know that within your function `bracemk-balance` variable `skeleton-pair` is a **free variable** - it's not bound by or within your function (not a function parameter and not bound with `let`, for example). It's not a lexically scoped variable; it's a dynamically scoped variable. It's not local to your function.

Emacs tells you this, for one thing, to let you know in case you misspelled a variable that ***is*** bound in your function. By misspelling it you can end up using a different, likely new, likely global variable.

See the Elisp manual, node [**Variable Scoping**](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Scoping.html).

Comment: Is there a better way to set up completion for parentheses?  Not quite so sure if I require `(setq skeleton-pair t)`.